# Pass struct to function C

Tags: c

Firstly, I am new to C programming and I wanted to know how can I pass a `struct` through a function?

For example :

```
typedef struct
{
 char name[20];
}info;

void message()
{
 info n;

 printf("Enter your name : ");
 scanf("%s", &n.name);
}
```

And I want to pass the entered name into this function so that it will print out the name.

```
void name()
{
printf("Good morning %s", ...);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &p.name);` should be `scanf("%19s", n.name);`

Comment: What in your C book about passing paramters to functions is not clear?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply pass a struct by value. That will create a copy of the data:

```
void name(info inf)
{
   printf("Good morning %s", inf.name);
}
```

Creating a struct whose only member is an array (as you did) is a known method to "pass arrays by value" (which is not normally possible).

For large structs it is common to just pass a pointer:

```
void name(info *inf)
{
   printf("Good morning %s", inf->name);
}
```

But changes to the pointer's target will then be visible to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Create the function definition that takes 'info' (struct) as a parameter:

```
void name (info);
```

Define the function as:

```
void name(info p) {
    printf("Good morning %s", p.name);
}
```

Then call the function appropriately:

```
name(n);
```

Comment: A declaration does not "create" a function. And that would add a signifgicant overhead for a large `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to print the name you can pass in a pointer to the string itself.

```
void name(char *str)
{
  printf("Good morning %s", str);
}
```

Called as `name(n.name);`

But let's assume this is a simplified example and you really want access to the whole struct inside the function. Normally you would pass in a pointer to the struct.

```
void name(info *ptr)
{
  printf("Good morning %s", ptr->name);
}
```

Called as `name(&n);`

Instead of using a pointer, you **can** pass in the whole struct by value, but this is not common as it makes a temporary copy of the whole struct.

```
void name(info inf)
{
  printf("Good morning %s", inf.name);
}
```

Called as `name(n);`

Comment: It does not **necessarily** copy the parameter struct. Especially if you declare it `const`, the compiler is free to just pass a pointer without copying, as long as the observable behaviour is the same.